# Shouldn't email address be excluded from Careers messaging data?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I am a curious person, and often I like seeing how pages are constructed.  I am conversing with a potential employer at the moment on StackOverflow Careers and to my amazement, I saw that their email address (unreleased explicitly to me) is included in the data retrieved on the `/messages/get-thread/` call.

I went through other messages in my inbox to see if phone was also included (it was null in my initial investigation but I thought it might have not been filled out) but it appears to not be transmitted.

Since this is a site specifically for those technically minded individuals (and some people looking for a job may get to be on the stalker side of desperate), this data being transmitted to the client is simple to get to (it took me about 2 minutes to open dev tools and find the appropriate call in the network tab while I was watching Raising Arizona) and could allow those aforementioned to initiate dialog with a potential employers rep in a more familiar way than they otherwise normally would.

Should the email address for the other party be removed from the message data retrieved from the server?

UPDATE
Actually, I ammend my previous message.  The potential employers email is displayed in a popup box on hover over an ellipses next to the message header.

Still, is it safe to so connect people, or is this a setting that the employers set in their profile (e.g. release my email to those to whom I message)?

Answer (score 1):

You're quite correct in that sender's contact information is shared when you are contacted by an employer and yours is shared when you reply or initiate communication with an employer. It's accessible from the ellipsis in the messaging part of Careers:

[image: Messaging]

This is a conscious decision and is spelled out in our privacy policy, in particular:

> Users who post profiles on our Careers site are generally doing so for the express purpose of getting connected with potential employers. So, if you post a profile on our Careers site, and choose to make your profile visible to employers, your name (which is required) and most of the other (optional) information in your profile will be visible to employers searching for candidates. That said, your contact information (email, phone, and address) will not be provided to employers in their candidate searches. We will only allow employers to have access to your contact information in two cases, both of which are under your control:
>
> - If you apply directly for a specific job, you will be asked to provide your name and email address (and other optional information) to the employer
> - If an employer finds you through a search and wants to contact you, we will ask if you are interested in hearing from them, and if you are, we will then provide them with your contact information.

I don't see any particular reason *why* the contact information shouldn't be shared, after all when you contact them via Careers they get an email anyway. From the candidate side we provide additional protection whereby you can block an employer. This prevents them seeing your contact information at all.